# A question about Thomae's function: trouble in understanding continuity at irrationals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to understand the well-known example of [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous only at irrationals.

I am unable to understand the continuity at irrationals. The main trouble is in understanding some fact about *irrationals, their open neighborhoods, and rationals in that neighborhood with some condition on their denominators.*

> **Q.** What is the crucial property of *irrationals, their (bounded) open neighborhoods and the rationals in that neighborhood* used in the this example?

Comment: Are you unable to understand the **dis**continuity at the rationals, or the continuity at the **ir**rationals?

Comment: Consider where reduced fractions with denominators of $2$ are located (at least a distance $1/2$ away from each other), where reduced fractions with denominators of $3$ are located (at least a distance $1/3$ away from each other), where reduced fractions with denominators $4$ are located (at least a distance of $1/4$ away from each other), $\dots,$ where reduced fractions with denominators of $319$ are located (at least a distance of $1/319$ from each other), $\ldots$.

Comment: Relevant (for the searches and keywords): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695819/sequence-of-continuous-function-converging-pointwise-to-thomaes-function

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910719/continuity-of-thomaes-function-at-irrationals answer your question?

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks for the link; this way I was thinking but not getting answer. I am actually interested in *property* of irrarionals (Especially open neighborhoods and rationals in it, satisfying some condition on denominators).

Comment: @Theo: Sorry; it was my (typo) mistake, and I edited it. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key property here is the following :

> Given any real number $\alpha$ and any positive integer $n$, there is a neighborhood $I$ of $\alpha$ such that if $x\in\mathbb {Q} \cap I, x\neq \alpha$ then $x$ has denominator greater than $n$.

The property above can be proved very easily. Consider two integers $a, b$ such that $a<\alpha <b$ and then consider all the rationals in interval $(a, b) $ with denominator less than equal to $n$. Clearly such rationals are finite in number and $k$ is their total count (exclude $\alpha$ if it is one of these rationals). Now the interval $[a, b] $ is divided into finitely many ($k+1$) subintervals and exactly one of these subintervals say $[c, d] $ contains $\alpha$ in its interior. The neighborhood $I=(c, d) $ satisfies the property mentioned above.

The continuity of Thomae function at irrationals is an immediate consequence of the above property. If $\alpha $ is an irrational point under consideration and $\epsilon>0$ be given then we choose integer $n>1/\epsilon$ and apply above property to get a neighborhood $I$ of $\alpha$. If $x\in I$ and $x=p/q$ is rational then $q>n$ and $f(x) = 1/q<1/n<\epsilon$ and if $x\in I$ is irrational then $f(x) =0$. In any case we have $x\in I\implies |f(x) - f(\alpha) |<\epsilon $ and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

Really, the only germane property that the rationals/irrationals have, in the construction of Thomae's functions, is that the rationals are countable and the two sets are complementary. You can generalise the construction like so:

1. Let $(x_n)$ be an injective sequence in $\Bbb{R}$.
2. Let $(y_n)$ be any sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ such that $y_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, and $y_n \to 0$.
3. Define
   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}y_n & \text{if there exists } n \in \Bbb{N} \text{ such that } x = x_n \\
   0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Thomae's function can be recovered by taking $(x_n)$ to be the sequence
$$0, 1, \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}, \color{green}{\frac{1}{3}}, \color{green}{\frac{2}{3}}, \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}, \color{red}{\frac{3}{4}}, \color{purple}{\frac{1}{5}}, \color{purple}{\frac{2}{5}}, \color{purple}{\frac{3}{5}}, \color{purple}{\frac{4}{5}}, \color{orange}{\frac{1}{6}}, \color{orange}{\frac{5}{6}}, \ldots$$
i.e. all rational numbers in $[0, 1]$ ordered lexicographically, first by the denominator of their lowest form, then by the numerator of their lowest form. Match it to a sequence $(y_n)$,
$$0, 1, \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}, \color{green}{\frac{1}{3}}, \color{green}{\frac{1}{3}}, \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}, \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}, \color{purple}{\frac{1}{5}}, \color{purple}{\frac{1}{5}}, \color{purple}{\frac{1}{5}}, \color{purple}{\frac{1}{5}}, \color{orange}{\frac{1}{6}}, \color{orange}{\frac{1}{6}}, \ldots$$
and you get Thomae's function. It's not too difficult to see that $y_n \to 0$; note that only finitely many terms will be larger than any given $\frac{1}{m}$ where $m \in \Bbb{N}$.

The generalised Thomae's function $f$ will be continuous at every point except at the $(x_n)$ points.

At each point $x_m$, any $\delta$-neighbourhood is an uncountable set, meaning a sequence like $(x_n)$ cannot cover the whole neighbourhood. Thus, in any $\delta$-neighbourhood, we will find values of $x$ such that $x \neq x_n$ for all $n$, and so $f(x) = 0$.

If we had continuity at $x_m$, then there would have to exist a $\delta > 0$, corresponding to $\varepsilon = |y_n| > 0$, i.e. such that
$$|x - x_m| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x_m)| < \varepsilon \implies |f(x) - y_n| < |y_n|.$$
But, if we let $x$ be an element of the $\delta$-neighbourhood around $x_m$ that doesn't belong to the sequence $(x_n)$, then $f(x) = 0$, so
$$|x - x_m| < \delta \implies |0 - y_n| < |y_n|,$$
a contradiction. Thus, $f$ is discontinuous at all points in the sequence $(x_n)$.

On the other hand, pick a point $x_0$ not in the sequence $(x_n)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $y_n \to 0$, there exists an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
$$n \ge N \implies |y_n| < \varepsilon.$$
Consider the set of "bad" points $\{x_1, \ldots, x_{N - 1}\}$. This set contains all points $x$ where $|f(x)| \ge \varepsilon$, and **it's finite**! Take $\delta$ to be the smallest distance from $x_0$ to any of the $N - 1$ points above, and then
$$|x - x_0| < \delta \implies x \notin \{x_1, \ldots, x_{N - 1}\} \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |f(x)| < |y_n| < \varepsilon,$$
proving continuity at $x_0$.